# Items - Orders Join table, hard to understand code of a restaurant app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm studying a the code for a Restaurant app. I'm stuck now, i don't understand the relation between the orders and the items. Looks like there is a joint table but i don't understand the logic of it. Here is the schema's code `

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160327212111) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.string  "cuisine_type"
    t.integer "price"
  end

  create_table "items_orders", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "order_id", null: false
    t.integer "item_id",  null: false
  end

  add_index "items_orders", ["item_id", "order_id"], name: "index_items_orders_on_item_id_and_order_id", using: :btree
  add_index "items_orders", ["order_id", "item_id"], name: "index_items_orders_on_order_id_and_item_id", using: :btree

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "party_id"
    t.boolean  "paid?",      default: false
  end
    end
```

And here the controller order's create method which confuses me even more.

```
  def create
    food_items = params[:item][:item_id].drop(1).map{ |item| item.to_i}
    @items = Item.where("id in (?)", food_items)
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
      # items_array = params[:item]["item_id"].drop(1)

    if @order.save
        @items.each { |item| @order.items << item }
        redirect_to orders_path
    else
      redirect_to new_order_path
    end
  end
```

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE models of item and order

```
    class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end

    class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
  has_one :party

end
```

Items and Orders Controller

```
    class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @item = Item.all
  end

  def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
    redirect_to items_path
    else
    redirect_to new_item_path
  end

  end

  def edit
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.update(item_params)
    redirect_to items_path
  end

  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy
    redirect_to items_path
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :cuisine_type, :price)
  end


end

    class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @orders = Order.order(:party_id)
    @items = Item.all
    @parties = Party.all
  end

  def show
    @orders = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @orders = Order.all
    @items = Item.all
    @parties = Party.all
  end

  def create
    puts "Item ids #{params[:item][:item_id]}"
    food_items = params[:item][:item_id].drop(1).map{ |item| item.to_i}
    @items = Item.where("id in (?)", food_items)
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
      # items_array = params[:item]["item_id"].drop(1)
    if @order.save
        @items.each { |item|
          @order.items << item
        }
        redirect_to orders_path
    else
      redirect_to new_order_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    @order.destroy
    redirect_to orders_path
  end


  private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:party_id, :item_id)
  end

end
```

Comment: Post your models, and which part of the controller code confuses you?

Comment: The relation between the `orders` and the `items` is `has_and_belongs_to_many`. You should see this if you look in either the `Order` or the `Item` models. The `items_orders` table exists to link the two tables together in this way; it is a standard approach in SQL databases.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it confuses me even more"*? Please be more specific. I can't explain, if I don't know what needs explaining. There may well be a better way to write that code, but I'd need to also see the corresponding view (and ideally, what `params` are sent to the controller) to advise.

Comment: I`ve added the controllers and the models. What i dont understand is the logic behind the create method of the Orders. I mean, looks so complicated, can someone explain it line by line for me? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per your schema, you must be having a [has-and-belongs-to-many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association between `Order` and `Item` classes.

**Disclaimer:** [It can easily be has-many-through](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) association instead of HABTM, but I don't see any extra column in the join table *items_orders*. Also you haven't mentioned any special use of `ItemsOrder` model (if one exists). So, I will go with the simpler one, HABTM.

**Models:**

```
class Order
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end

class Item
  has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
end
```

With these associations in place, you can do these operations:

```
# Say, you have some items in your database
item = Item.take
 => #<Item id: 1>

Order.count
 => 0

# Create a new order and assign `item` to it
order = Order.new
order.items << item
order.save!
```

Above set of statements will insert a new record in join table as such:

```
| id | order_id | item_id |
| 1  | 1        | 1       |
```

Now, you can check items present in an order as:

```
order.items
 => [#<Item id: 1>, ...]
```

Or the inverse:

```
item.orders
 => [#<Order id: 1>, ...]
```

Now, lets go through the controller code:

```
def create
  # I don't know what `params[:item][:item_id]` contains, but `drop` method drops the first n (in this case, 1) number of elements and returns the remaining array
  # ... and map is changing each element from whatever format to integer format
  # Read more:
  #   - https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/drop
  #   - https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/map
  food_items = params[:item][:item_id].drop(1).map { |item| item.to_i }

  # Searching for items with ID ANY IN given array of IDs
  @items = Item.where("id in (?)", food_items)

  # Initialize a new order with permitted params (hopefully). Check definition of `order_params `
  @order = Order.new(order_params)

  if @order.save
    # Assigning each searched item to new order, which will create as many new records in join table as the number of `@items`
    @items.each { |item| @order.items << item }

    # The usual
    redirect_to orders_path
  else
    # Shouldn't it be render, and not redirect
    redirect_to new_order_path
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I`ve added the models and the controllers.

Comment: I really dont understand this create logic                                                          
food_items = params[:item][:item_id].drop(1).map { |item| item.to_i }                   
and also this one @items = Item.where("id in (?)", food_items)

Comment: Did you check all the links I provided? Did you try inspecting what `params[:item][:item_id]` looks like?

Comment: Yes i checked the links and i understand what those methods does. But why need to drop the first element? And how i can inspect this? params[:item][:item_id] throught the console, i'm using postgresql. You told me what the create method's code does, but you didn't tell me why :) what i don't understand is the logic flow. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean _"you didn't tell me why"_?

Comment: _"But why need to drop the first element? "_ - I don't know. May be because your params are structured that way. I can't tell.

Comment: You can inspect it by installing gem [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) and then inserting `byebug` as the first statement in your create action. The control flow will stop at that point and you can the values of different params. OR, you can check the server logs to see the request params.

Comment: why it looks for a double attribute?                                                   
food_items = params[:item][:item_id].drop(1).map{ |item| item.to_i} Why not simply params[:item_id]??                              this is my post request                                                                                    
<%= collection_select(:item, :item_id, @items, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}) %>

Comment: "item"=>{"item_id"=>["", "3"]} this is what i have in my params sending the post request and now after two days i understand this code here params[:item][:item_id].drop(1) xD xD xD .. it`s just a nested hash and he drops the empty value in the array.

Comment: I still don`t understand this last line of code @order.items << item, from the create method it iterates throught this (byebug) @items
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Item id: 1, name: "Pizza", cuisine_type: "Classica", price: 10>, #<Item id: 2, name: "Pasta alla puttanesca", cuisine_type: "Pasta", price: 12>]> and put each element into the variable @order.items.

Comment: and after in the console i see SELECT "items".* FROM "items" INNER JOIN "items_orders" ON "items"."id" = "items_orders"."item_id" WHERE "items_orders"."order_id" = $1  [["order_id", 22]] and in buybug if i run @order.items i see now..
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Item id: 2, name: "Pasta alla puttanesca", cuisine_type: "Pasta", price: 12>, #<Item id: 3, name: "Crescenza", cuisine_type: "Classica", price: 2>]> please help me it driving me crazy :/ how can it knows to join the inner table to do all this?